# Using exec() in PHP to run a PSEXEC command

Tags: php, psexec

So I am using the EXEC() command in PHP to call PSEXEC, but it keeps failing and I cant figure out why... Im literally pulling my hair out here.

Here is my code:

```
exec('psexec \\\\<server.domain> -accepteula -u <username> -p <password> PING <someurl>', $cmdOutput, $err);
echo $cmdOutput;
echo $err;
```

I tried double slashes (\) and single slashes ().

Im using PING as somthing simple - just trying to get it to work before I execute the actual program. The output is:
    `2250Array`

if I just do

```
exec('ping <someurl>');
```

it works but I cant get this PSEXEC to work...

I tried `SYSTEM()` and that doesnt work either. Can't find any info on error code 2250. Tried monitoring the processes using PROCMON but no usable info from that.

Comment: Is psexec in your shell environment's path, or at least in the same directory as your php script? You may have to specify a full absolute `c:/program files/putty/psexec.exe` type path if not.

Comment: PSEXEC is in my system32 folder AND in the same directory as the PHP script. I have also tried the full path and the same exact error code.

Comment: whats the psexec command that works when executed from the command line.  Sometimes you need to put the whole command in " (Double Quotes)

Comment: I've tried "PING GOOGLE.COM" and PING "GOOGLE.COM", and no change

Comment: If you are using single quote `'` use  2 slashes instead of 4

Comment: Do a `var_dump($cmdOutput)`. PHP puts an array of strings of output into that argument, not a string.

Comment: Changed the slashes, and no effect. The var_dump($cmdOutput) returns nothing. Any ideas on how to narrow down the issue? I just cant think of any more troubleshooting steps